# Fiddler HTTPS Decrypt causes HttpClient to throw "Task was canceled" exception when used with AutoResponder

Tags: encryption, dotnet-httpclient, fiddler

My app calls an external API, to avoid flooding them with test requests I decided to use Fiddler's AutoResponder to catch the request and respond with a specific response.

The issue that I am running into is that the request is HTTPS, so Fiddler has to be configured to decrypt HTTPS traffic to trigger the AutoResponder rule, but then HttpClient throws a "Task is canceled" exception.

If I turn off HTTPS decryption, then the call goes out to the external API and returns a response, so I know that the code is working as expected.

I am assuming it could be that the AutoResponder's response is not encrypted, or something about the encryption is incorrect.

I have trusted the Fiddler certificate.

Comment: Is that everything that is shown in the `Log` tab of Fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the response data did not end with two line breaks.

Adding the line breaks made HttpClient read the response and continue processing as expected.